# .NET Windows Forms mouse enter effect for ALL existing PictureBox controls

Tags: c#, windows, forms, hover, components

I'm new here, and this is my first post here. My apologies if I don't follow the standards on creating a new question here on SO.

I've been racking my brains for the past couple of hours to try to program a custom class which would allow me to add a new property to existing PictureBox controls, allowing me to set a Color to my custom property, which would result in setting a border with the selected color as the user hovers the control.

Below is the code I've written so far:

```
[ProvideProperty("HoverColor", typeof(PictureBox))]
public class PictureBoxHover : Component, IExtenderProvider
{
    private readonly Dictionary<IntPtr, Color> _hoverColors;
    public PictureBoxHover()
    {
        _hoverColors = new Dictionary<IntPtr, Color>();
    }
    public bool CanExtend(object extendee)
    {
        return (extendee is PictureBox);
    }
    public Color GetHoverColor(PictureBox picb)
    {
        Color color;
        if (_hoverColors.TryGetValue(picb.Handle, out color))
            return color;
        return Color.Empty;
    }
    public void SetHoverColor(PictureBox picb, Color color)
    {
        Color hoverColor;
        _hoverColors[picb.Handle] = color;
    }
}
```

The above code adds the custom property "HoverColor" to all existing PictureBox controls in my solution - just as I need. All I need to do now is somehow have it draw a border around my PictureBoxes with the set color when the user hovers over the control.

I DON'T want my class to inherit the PictureBox or Control classes, as that would require having to change all my PictureBoxes from the ordinaly PictureBox to my custom PictureBox - which is why I instead want to 'append' this custom property and functionality to the ordinary PictureBox control.

Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

Comment: Inheriting is of course exactly what you should do.  Having existing controls isn't a problem, just Search + Replace in the Designer.vb file.

Comment: Yeah I know I could do that - but it's definitely not the approach I wish to take. This could make things inconsistent, as there may be controls which for some reason I don't update (replace). I also want it to be easily manageable in the sense that I could add/remove the extender whenever I want and have it reflect my controls without having to adjust the code.

Comment: That's not how SO works, answers are supposed to be useful to more than one person.  Try a forum.

Comment: Are you kidding me? I've searched all over the internet including SO itself and didn't find an answer. I'm certain that an answer to this question would help MANY users. This would allow anyone to apply hover styling effects on Windows Forms Controls. How is this not useful to more than one person?

Comment: Hmya, didn't expect you to be thrilled by that comment.  Did it occur to you that, even after a long search, you didn't find anything useful because it just isn't the right way to solve the problem?  The extra thing you have to do in GetHoverColor is to subscribe the pb's Paint event so you can do your own painting.  You also need a way to unsubscribe it when the programmer decides he doesn't want to alter the control.  And fingers crossed that your Paint event runs last.  No guarantee but that usually works.

Comment: I agree with Hans. Inherit is definitely the better approach here. Unless you have a ton of picturebox controls on your form it's not that much work to do search/replace in a designer file.

Comment: Thanks Hans and Abdias for your responses. I wanted the approach of using the Extender rather than inheriting the control because of the way it works and can be easily managed. I know that the end result would be the same, but the way it works is different.
Edit: Whoops, hit the return key by mistake. Anyway, I'll take your suggestions and inherit the PictureBox class, and replace the existing intances of the PictureBox with my own control which inherits the standard PictureBox. Thanks again to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could achieve your goal simpler by using custom user control instead of creating extended properties for picture box. Below is a simple sample:

```
public class FramedPictureBox : UserControl
{
    private readonly PictureBox _pictureBox;

    public FramedPictureBox()
    {
        const int FRAME_SIZE = 3;
        _pictureBox = new PictureBox
                          {
                              Left = FRAME_SIZE,
                              Top = FRAME_SIZE,
                              Width = Width - 2*FRAME_SIZE,
                              Height = Height - 2*FRAME_SIZE,
                              Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top
                          };

        _pictureBox.MouseEnter += OnPictureBoxMouseEnter;
        _pictureBox.MouseLeave += OnPictureBoxMouseLeave;

        Controls.Add(_pictureBox);
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        var image = new Bitmap(_pictureBox.Width, _pictureBox.Height);
        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
        graphics.Clear(Color.White);

        _pictureBox.Image = image;

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    private void OnPictureBoxMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

    private void OnPictureBoxMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi yBee, and many thanks for your reply. Yeah I am aware of that possibility, but I didn't want to create a custom control (I had also specified this in my question). Imagine the scenario where you wanted to add this new functionality to an existing application. That would require having to replace all controls within each form. Also, I was trying to learn more about adding custom properties which is why I wanted to try implementing things that way - I was aware of the other options & possibilities I had. Thanks nonetheless for your reply though :)